# Using Jquery in Custom Post Template

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am new to jquery but was able to come up with this - http://jsfiddle.net/t2x9G/3/

I am building in wordpress and trying to figure out how to make the new text that populates come from a post instead of embedded in the code.

```
$('#navone').click(function(){
 $('#title').text("#1 title");
 $('#content').text("This is the text from number one");
});
```

I would like the new text to be editable on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

So what you're looking to do is call the post from the WordPress Database and dynamically replace the content on the view without reloading the page?  Try this tutorial:

[How To AJAXify WordPress Theme](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2010/05/how-to-ajaxify-wordpress-theme.html)

Comment: Thanks for the resource. I will have to work through it and see if it is what I am looking to do.